# content access alternative for drupal 7

Tags: 7, users

I need exactly this module: http://drupal.org/project/content_access which unfortunatly does not work anymore with drupal 7.18 and i dont want to search for the problem right now...

so is there any alternative? I need it to restrict users which are not in the role x to view certain sites.

Comment: _"i dont want to search for the problem right now"_ - Not the best attitude to bring to this site I'm afraid. Doing your own research is a requirement before asking questions

Comment: the problem is one system method does not return the right type anymore... so i had to fix the module... but i dont have the time right now to dig into a completly unknown module and fix things. :/

Comment: Ah so you have done research ;) Make sure you add what you know to the question, it'll save someone trying to answer the question doing the same digging you've already done. If you can explain what system call has changed, and as much as you know about how this has affected the module, I think you'll get a quicker response

Answer (score 3):

[Simple Access](http://drupal.org/project/simple_access) module may come to your rescue. Do check it out.

Comment: Simple Access worked for me, when Content Access did not.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Context](http://drupal.org/project/context) to see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Or just fix the problem in content_access: http://drupal.org/node/1721758#comment-6676340

it does not fix the problem that content_access is quite old and not regulary maintained but it fixes as long as it takes to migrate to another module